# Using perror with arguments

Tags: c

Is it common to pass arguments to `perror()`, or is it usually used for a very generic message. For example, something like:

```
char buffer[50];
sprintf(buffer, "The file %s could not be opened", filename);
perror(buffer);
```

The reason I ask is because it seems the single arg to `perror` must be a string literal (without any format specifiers), and so perhaps it discourages using any variables?

Or, is there a shortform way to do something like:

```
perror("The file %s could not be opened", filename);
```

(Perhaps a macro?)

Comment: One alternative: `int en = errno; fprintf(stderr, "The file %s could not be opened: %s\n", filename, strerror(en));`

Comment: @kaylum is there a global variable or something with "last error" in C, or how does `perror` know what to print?

Comment: Yes that's [errno](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html)

Comment: @David542 the man page says "The <errno.h> header file defines the integer variable errno, which is set by system calls and some library functions in the event of an error to indicate what went wrong." So yes, I think it is a global variable.

Comment: @David542 [`perror`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/perror) "*prints a textual description of the error code currently stored in the system variable errno to stderr.*". Anything you do to build the string passed to `perror` must be guaranteed to *not* modify `errno` otherwise you'll get the wrong error message displayed. In particular, `sprintf` may potentially change `errno` so you have to be doubly careful there.

Comment: I usually use whatever string I have, (for example, the filename,) but barring that, just a string literal that says the broad intent of the code as an argument. I'd like to see someone more experienced share their thoughts on best-practices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`perror` is declared as:

```
void perror(const char *s);
```

From the man page:

> First (if s is not NULL and *s is not a null byte ('\0')), the argument string s is printed, followed by a colon and a blank.  Then an error message corresponding to the current value of errno and a new-line.

From that, we then can assume that `perror` is basically defined as:

```
fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", s, strerror(errno));
```

As a macro, it could be implemented as:

```
#define MY_PERROR(FMT,...) \
  fprintf(stderr, FMT ": %s\n", ##__VA_ARGS__, strerror(errno))
```

Based on your example the usage would be:

```
MY_PERROR("The file %s could not be opened", filename);
```

The output would look like:

The file <*filename*> could not be opened: <*result of strerror*>

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
#include <string.h> /* for strerror()    */
#include <errno.h>  /* for errno         */
#include <stdlib.h> /* for EXIT_FAILURE  */
#include <fcntl.h>  /* open and O_RDONLY */

...

    if ((fd = open(file, O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "open: %s: %s (errno = %d)\n",
                filename,
                strerror(errno),
                errno);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

and you are free of using whatever parameters you like.